# Running Malware In VirtualBox

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, malware

For a project I am working on I want to collect data of malware in a virtualbox for 30 seconds and then revert the VirtualBox back to its original state and repeat this process 500 times for 500 different malware links that I have in a txt file. Before I revert to the normal VirtualBox state, I want to collect data from a program that is monitoring that malware. What is the best way to do this?

Edit: I'd also like to point out that I have code to read the opcodes that are being used by the application. All I would like to do is automate this process for the virtualbox.

Comment: As a starting point, I'd recommend you to take a look at platforms such as [Cuckoo Sandbox](https://cuckoosandbox.org/) or [Sandboxed Execution Environment](https://github.com/F-Secure/see).

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of such a feature in virtualbox or vmware but you can always use third party tools to compare the state of the different parts (like registry) before and after the execution of malwares.
I heard Ashampoo unistaller is a great tool to do the job but personally never tested it before.

Another option is to use sanboxes like sandboxie or cuckoo sandbox to capture the changes.

Another option is to use online sandboxes like hybrid-analysis which is perfect for what you want to do.

Just keep in mind that most malwares use anti-VM techniques to prevent execution in VMs so you probably will not be able to capture all the features of the malwares.

Hope it helps.